# Visual Studio 2010: firefox as browser

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to use firefox as the standard browser with visual studio 2010?

I have some problems when logging with internet explorer, so i use firefox for testing my sharepoint webparts. But when i want to test the code (with some breakpoints for example), VS opens by default IE, where i face again my login problems.
So i need a way to debug with firefox, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364723/how-do-i-set-my-development-web-browser-in-vs2010).

Basically, it means you should right-click on an aspx-page, select 'Browse with...' and select the browser of your choice in the popup. You can also set the 'Default' in this popup.

Comment: I'm not sure of what i'm searching... I don't have any aspx file in my poject folder =O

Comment: In that case you could create a new web project and set the default browser from there. VS should remember the setting.

Answer (score 1):

I have alreadx found the solution: just set firefox (or the desired browser) as the default browser, because VS will always open the default one

Comment: Mark your this as your correct answer so others can quickly find your solution :)

Comment: It tells me i have to wait 26 hours...